# Android Studio Emulator Error ( Forticlient Blocks Android )

Tags: android, proxy, emulation

ı am using android studio. but my computer has fortiguard and forticlient.ıt blocks repository and other things which i dont know because ı am newbie about android.
ı uploaded repostiory manually.ı solved repository problem but now when ı run my hello world app ı got this error.how can i solve this problem ?

> 12:52 Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open
>   C:\Users\computername.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin:
>   Permission denied
>
> 12:54 Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>
> 12:54 Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input
>   failed
>
> 12:54 Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

what should i do ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: ıt ıs hello world app.Do you want to see codes still ?

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

- filter the logcat by your application, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4dTw.png);
- restart and clean the android studio, File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart;
- uninstall app, disable instant run, then install it again, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn7UU.png);